# Is it possible to create multiple Node.js HTTP servers, and access them via a request URL (not a subdomain)?

Tags: node.js, http

Let's say I had a few separate HTTP servers made in node, each with a unique ID attached to them. Is there any way to access them with request URLs based on that id? For example:

Server ifjw48n: accessible via http://example.com/ifjw48n

Server ty58u7e: accessible via http://example.com/ty58u7e

Comment: Probably with a proxy server doing routing to each particular nodejs instance.  I am assuming that each of your http servers is listening on a different port.

Comment: If you were using a framework such as express, you could send each route to a completely separate module, yet use the same server (if that's not doable, yes, use a proxy but that simply increases overhead). What is the necessity of running two servers for what appears to be the same domain in your example?

Comment: I'm trying to create "private" servers for different clients on a specific request, such as: Client make a POST request containing a variable, and a webserver is created using that variable in it.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you can do this with nginx used as a routing proxy.  Similar question in a different stackexchange forum answered here: [Routing to various node.js servers on same machine](https://serverfault.com/questions/208656/routing-to-various-node-js-servers-on-same-machine).

From that answer, here's a sample config that does routing based on the URL:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location /foo {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
    }

    location /bar {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9001;
    }

    location /baz {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9002;
    }
}
```

Comment: @skeeballassault - does this answer work for you?  Anything else you need?